# Intel Vt-x - Android emulator

Tags: virtualization, android, vt-x

I'm trying to improve the speed of the Android emulator by installing Intel Haxm. I've downloaded all that's necessary from the Android SDK but when I try to install the software for Intel, I get an error saying that my computer has the capabilities to use Vt-x but it's not enabled.

I checked my BIOS and Virtualization is enabled (option is: Vtx Only). I therefore don't see why I can't install that program properly.

My computer:

- Toshiba Satellite Ultrabook i3 Intel Core
- Processor: [Intel® Core™ i3-3217U Processor 
  (3M Cache, 1.80 GHz)](http://ark.intel.com/products/65697/Intel-Core-i3-3217U-Processor-(3M-Cache-1_80-GHz))

Comment: I would try posting this on StackOverflow.

Answer (score -2):

I think you need to set it on your Task Manager too. In the Details tab, right click on the application you want to use Virtualization in, and enable the UAC Virtualization.

Comment: Can you edit your answer after you verify it actually is applicable?